# Build templates using HTML/CSS

Tags: html

If you are building a simple website using just simple HTML/CSS/Javascript that has say 5 pages, is it possible to build a template so that the headers and navigation can be called in each page?

Comment: This is easily possible if you are using a server side script like PHP or ASP.NET, otherwise you should just create a template HTML file and create new pages from that template.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I will try [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) as suggested by @David Dorward.

Comment: Are you using Apache? That has server side includes. I've never used them but I know they are there

Comment: David Dorward said I don't need server side. Thanks for bringing it up. I will follow up.

Comment: Yes, you can do this without server side. AJAX will allow you to. Server side is preferable though, as it guarantees that the page will be served with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use JavaScript to generate content, this is a bad idea (for all the usual reasons that having JavaScript that isn't unobtrusive isn't a good idea).

You should use either a proper template system or an include system.

I would suggest looking at the [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) utility that is part of [Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/). It generates static files, so you don't need any particular server side support to use it.

Comment: Are you sure we don't need server side? Even Apache?

Comment: Yes. You run it, and you get static files out. If you want it to be accessible over HTTP then you will need a web server of some sort  ... but static files work find if you point your browser at them on your hard disk, so you don't need Apache (or any other server) for the template engine to work. (This also means that you can run the template engine on your workstation and then upload the result to a server, so you don't need to install TT on your server at all)

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript and CSS, yes, the HTML, without something like server side includes or a dynamic language doing its own inclusion, no.

The only option without using the above is if you use frames, or an iframe, but they have their own issues you have to content with.

Otherwise, you will need to just bite the bullet and have duplicate code across all your pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a header.html, a footer.html and then regular content, and fetch the header/footer with AJAX every time, placing it before and after the content. A server side scripting language would be easier, but this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure about this but can it not be done with XSLT and XML?

Answer (score 1):

use a scripting language such as asp or php is best option.

option 2 is to use iframes and option 3 is if you don't have access to a scripting language such as ASP or PHP, and don't want to use iframes you could use jQuery and use $.get() to load header and footer files into named DIV's after the page load. that would require javascript and would be FAR from optimal.